# How can I integrate Python mido and asyncio?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, mido

I have a device which does file I/O over MIDI. I have a script using Mido that downloads files but it is a mess of global variables. I want to tidy it up to use asyncio properly but I am not sure how to integrate the mido callback. I think the documentation says I should use a Future object but I am not sure how the mido callback function can obtain that object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`mido` provides a [callback-based](https://mido.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ports.html#callbacks) API which will invoke the callback from a different thread. Your implementation of the callback can communicate with asyncio by calling [`loop.call_soon_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.call_soon_threadsafe). Note that you won't be able to just set the value of a [`Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future) because the callback will be called multiple times, and a future can only be set once - it is meant for one-shot computations.

A common pattern for multiply invoked callbacks is to push events onto an asyncio [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio-queues) and pop stuff from it in asyncio code. This can be made even more convenient by exposing the queue as an async iterator. This function automates the process:

```
def make_stream():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    def callback(message):
        loop.call_soon_threadsafe(queue.put_nowait, message)
    async def stream():
        while True:
            yield await queue.get()
    return callback, stream()
```

`make_stream` returns two objects:

- a *callback*, which you can pass to `mido.open_input()`
- a stream, which you can iterate with [`async for`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/) to get new messages

Whenever the callback is invoked by mido in its background thread, your asyncio `async for` loop iterating over the stream will wake up with a new item. Effectively, `make_stream` converts a threaded callback into an async iterator. For example (untested):

```
async def print_messages():
    # create a callback/stream pair and pass callback to mido
    cb, stream = make_stream()
    mido.open_input(callback=cb)

    # print messages as they come just by reading from stream
    async for message in stream:
        print(message)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for but all it does print for me is an endless stream of 
<generator object Queue.get at 0x1080fc150>
<generator object Queue.get at 0x1080fc0f8> regardless if I send any MIDI data. I understand it is untested, but I have a hard time figuring out what is wrong..

Comment: I changed `yield queue.get()` into `yield await queue.get()`. That did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @Genoil You're right! `queue` is an asyncio queue, so its `get()` method is a coroutine and must be awaited, duh! BTW what version of Python are you using?

Comment: we are on 3.6.10

Comment: @Genoil Thanks, that explains the output that says **generator** object Queue.get, and which threw me off at first - `asyncio.Queue` was modified to use `async def` for Python 3.7. You might want to consider switching to a newer version; Python 3.7 was released almost two years ago.